# How to perform STIntersect between a polygon and point geometryfile?

Tags: sql-server

What I have so far:

```
select Metro.Object_ID 
from Geocoding_tab.dbo.Part1_Part2_Combined_Final as paypal
    ,Object_id.dbo.All_Combined_9_Metros as Metro
where paypal.geom.STIntersect(Metro.GEOM) = 1;
```

Comment: Why are you not using proper `join`s and what is your desired output?

Comment: @iamdave actually i am new to mssql software. so i am not sure of the joins. Could you please help me with it ?

Comment: @iamdave i have 2 files : the "paypal" one is a point file and the "Metro" one is a polygon file.
i have primary keys in both the tables. I want to know in which Metro Polygon each of the Paypal points fall in . Denoted by their Primary key.

Comment: why are you talking about "files"? Are these not tables?

Comment: @Cool_Br33ze yes they are spatial tables in the database

Answer (score 0):

You can amend the query to use JOIN syntax

```
SELECT Metro.Object_ID 
FROM
    Geocoding_tab.dbo.Part1_Part2_Combined_Final as paypal
INNER JOIN 
    Object_id.dbo.All_Combined_9_Metros as Metro ON paypal.geom.STIntersects(Metro.GEOM) = 1;
```

**EDIT** - following error shown in comments below

You can use the [STIsValid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/spatial-geometry/stisvalid-geometry-data-type) Method to detect if you have shape that's invalid.  The method will return 0 if invalid.

The [MakeValid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/spatial-geography/makevalid-geography-data-type) Method will fix invalid shape data

for example:

```
UPDATE table SET geom = geom.MakeValid() where geom.STIsValid() = 0
```

**Note**

As the error suggests, the MakeValid could alter your shape in a way that you might consider incorrect, depending on the original problem with the shape. So you should confirm that you're happy with the  "corrected" shape before proceeding.

Comment: error message with running the code: Msg 6522, Level 16, State 1, Line 34
A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user-defined routine or aggregate "geometry": 
System.ArgumentException: 24144: This operation cannot be completed because the instance is not valid. Use MakeValid to convert the instance to a valid instance. Note that MakeValid may cause the points of a geometry instance to shift slightly.
System.ArgumentException: 
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeometry.ThrowIfInvalid()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeometry.STIntersects(SqlGeometry other)

Comment: This error usually occurs if the polygon wasn't drawn left to right

Comment: so what is the probable solution to this issue ?